# Jquery Ajax + ASP MVC 3 Forms

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ajax

I am currently writing a simple web app which needs to update form changes via Ajax requests.

I did some Ajax based calls in MVC1 but haven't touched it since, and I believe we were using MicrosoftAjax not JQuery. So I have read that Microsoft is currently going with JQuery and dropping MicrosoftAjax, and im a bit confused as to how I get my form to communicate with my mvc action. There is also talk of Unobtrusive Javascript, which seems to relate to Ajax calls, but im finding it all a tad confusing getting a solid example of how to use Jquery with MVC3 to call an action and return a result...

```
public AjaxController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult AjaxAction(SomeModel model)
    {
        //...Do Stuff
    }
}

<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Form goes here -->
    </body>
</html>
```

So should I be using Html.FormBegin, or AjaxBegin etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to MVC3 with jQuery is quite simple.

There is an upgrade tool for MVC1-> MVC2: http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2010/03/10/migrating-asp-net-mvc-1-0-applications-to-asp-net-mvc-2-rtm.aspx

And a tool to upgrade from MVC2 -> MVC3 http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcinon/archive/2011/01/13/mvc-3-project-upgrade-tool.aspx

You can also read the release document to see how to manually upgrade.

For the AJAX part, once you put the right files into your project (Create a new MVC3 project, and copy all the javascript files to your current project.) and reference those scripts instead of MSAjax, you should be ready to go.

The unobtrusive part, is also super easy. See http://yobriefcase.posterous.com/unobtrusive-javascript-in-mvc3

Basically just add some settings in your web.config, and reference the right javascripts, and your done.

In the end, you probably don't have to change anything in your code, just reference the right files and you'r done.

Comment: Sorry, I think im confusing matters, this is not a migration project, its a new fresh MVC3 project. I was just basing my knowledge of MVC and Ajax on my previous encounters with it, will give a read to the bits above though.

Comment: Forgot about this question, I was ideally after someone to just tell me the Javascript includes and the form/actions to use to have JQuery to the ajax call, found out it should be Ajax.BeginForm() not Html.BeginForm with all the Jquery includes, will give this the answer as its quite informative about the unobtrusive javascript.